# How to read and parse gitconfig file with node.js?

Tags: node.js, config, ini, git-config

```
[user]
        name = Alvin J. Alexander
        email = [omitted]
[merge]
        tool = vimdiff
```

This is what `~/.gitconfig` file looks like. I've never encountered such data objects before. Does this format have a name like json files? Or is this a custom format?

My goal is to extract data from this file to fill out a `package.json` template. I want to research this format to better understand how to parse it. Do parsing functions already exist for this?

---

## For Reference

This is a template for how to parse it:

(requires `iniparser` module to be installed)

```
var iniparser = require('iniparser');
  var fs = require('fs');
  var home_dir = process.env.HOME || process.env.HOMEPATH || process.env.USERPROFILE;
  console.log (home_dir);
  var config_file = home_dir+'/.gitconfig';
  var exists = fs.existsSync(config_file);
  if (exists) {
    console.log("Getting some information from the git configuration...");
    var config = iniparser.parseSync(config_file);
    console.log(config);
    return config;
  }
  else {
    console.log("Git configuration file does not exist...");
    return {};
  };
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This file is a `ini` file. You can try [this](https://www.npmjs.org/package/ini) parser, but any node-ini parser should do the job :).

Comment: Well, isn't this embarrassing. I guess too much web programming and new toys are preventing me from exploring the basics and makes me forget them :) Thank you!

Comment: A git config file is not exactly the same as a INI file... for instance, sections can have names e.g. `[submodule "mysubmodule"]`

Comment: Is there a reason for recommending "node-iniparser" over https://www.npmjs.org/package/ini? The latter has vastly larger community.

Comment: I just randomly googled. That's why I put that last sentence there :). I'llc hange it.